# How to auto zoom model

Tags: html, css

I have modal which is shown after some seconds of page load.

The content of modal is the facebook page

Visit [here](http://www.baidtransports.co.in) to see the modal. (Wait for 3-4 secs)

I want that modal to be auto zoomed, as per screen

My Modal CSS:-

```
 <style type="text/css">
.fb_self{
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #999;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
border-radius: 6px;
outline: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
padding: 5px;
}
.fbhide{
display:none;
}
.fbshow{
            position: fixed;
            color: #000000;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            /* To align popup window at the center of screen*/
                top: 75;
            left: 50%;

            margin-left: -170px;

}


</style>
```

My Modal HTML:

```
<div id="fbmy_div" class="fbhide">
<div class="fbmy_div">
<div class="fb_self">
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/baidtransports/" data-tabs="timeline,messages" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" >
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/baidtransports/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/baidtransports/">Baid Transport Company</a>
</blockquote></div>
</br></br><center>
<span class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll" onclick="fbfunccl()">Close</span></center>.
</div></div></div>
```

I want that Facebook modal to be auto zoomed and fit the screen.

Comment: Have you tried to use `vh`, `vw` (Viewport-percentage lengths) units? That is, setting `width` of the modal to `width: 100vw` and height to `height: 90vh` ? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Comment: No, if I do that, so in which div I should use?

Comment: `width: 100vw;` on `fbmy_div` and `min-height: 90vh` on `.fb_self`